# How to extract xip archive using command line?

Tags: xcode, macos, xcode8, osx-elcapitan, macos-sierra

I searched around how to extract XIP archive using command line with no luck so I am leaving my own solution, as a `bash` function, here.

I found my inspiration [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37812664/end-of-central-directory-signature-not-found-when-installing-xcode-8-beta-xip).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extract .xip files into a specific folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42197588/extract-xip-files-into-a-specific-folder)

Comment: Having asnwered both: I am in favor of removing this as a dupe as well. I have cleaned up the other question and believe it should suffice.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```bash
function unxip()
{
    [ -z "$1" ] && echo "usage: unxip /path/to/archive.xip" && return

    # http://newosxbook.com/src.jl?tree=listings&file=pbzx.c
    PBZX="/usr/local/src/pbzx/pbzx" && [ ! -x "$PBZX" ] && echo "$PBZX not found." && return

    [ ! -f "$1" ] && echo "$1 not found." && return

    [ -f "Content" ] || [ -f "Metadata" ] && echo "Content or Metadata already exists." && return

    pkgutil --check-signature "$1" && xar -xf "$1" && "$PBZX" Content | sudo tar x --strip-components=1

    rm "Content" "Metadata"
}
```

We first check for `xip` file signature then extract its contents using `xar`. We then use Jonathan Levin [pbzx](http://newosxbook.com/src.jl?tree=listings&file=pbzx.c) to properly unpack `pbzx` chunks and pipe the output to `tar`, skipping `.` to avoid overwriting current working directory permissions.

This does the trick to unpack `Xcode8.xip` archives on OS X El Capitan.

Comment: This is undesirable from a CI point of view since it requires installing a third party app when native tools (/System/Library/CoreServices/Applications/Archive Utility.app/Contents/MacOS/Archive Utility) installed on the system already perform the work.

Comment: @ablarg from a CI point of view: how can the Archive Utility be feasibly integrated into a shell script to achieve automation? Can it be scripted? Or did you think of double-clicking the XIP archive?

Comment: @rexford if you just do `open -W archive.xip` from terminal that will launch bomArchiveHelper and unpack the xip in the current directory and will block until the unarchive is complete. I use this to open Xcode.xip via a shell call in Jenkins all the time. The -W flag tells the shell to wait for the application invoked to exit before proceeding.

Comment: Upvoted, but see below for an easier solution: `brew install thii/unxip/unxip` also unxips correctly Xcode archives, unlike Apple tools. (but it needs compilation of the `pbzx` tool from source, which needs to also build a custom lib....)

Answer (score 40):

You could try:

`xip -x [path to .xip file]`

Comment: This is the way.

Answer (score 14):

On macOS Mojave (not sure about other OS versions), navigate to the directory into which you’d like to expand the contents, then run `xip --expand /path/to/xip.xip`. For instance:

```
iMac:Applications jeff$ xip --expand /Users/jeff/Downloads/Xcode_11_Beta.xip
```

Comment: I've just checked that in macOS High Sierra (10.13.6) this command works as well, although not mentioned in 'man xip', curiously. I had some authentication issue which re-downloading the file from developer.apple.com cleared it.

Comment: I can confirm that `xip --expand` works in 10.12 Sierra & 10.11 El Capitan as well, even though it wasn't added to the man page until macOS 10.14.

Answer (score 8):

Use [unxip](https://github.com/thii/Unxip). You can install it with Homebrew:

```
brew install thii/unxip/unxip
```

To extract a `.xip` file:

```
unxip path/to/.xip
```

Comment: Unxiping XCode 10.1 was not working with Unarchiver... but this did the trick, thanks!

Comment: this save me countless hours of frustrations. thanks. I used this to extract Xcode_12.5.1.xip

Comment: @IeeCoder It's been stuck for me on `Expanding items from “Xcode_12.5.1.xip”: 99%` for quite a while now. shall I give up? (what's wrong with that xip? no tool to extract it...)

Answer (score 6):

`open -W archive.xip` will work better since it will then block until the archive has finished opening.

Answer (score 0):

On MacOS Monterey 12.7 the following worked for me:

1. Download the
2. Extract xip archive: `xip --expand ~/Downloads/Xcode_14.3.1.xip`
3. Ignore warning message `xip: signing certificate was "Software Update" (validation not attempted)`
4. Wait a very very long time for archive to extract with no feedback (I did it overnight)
5. Move expanded folder to /Applications: `sudo mv Xcode.app /Applications`
6. To run Xcode you must use full path to executable or lese you will get an error: `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode`

Answer (score -1):

In my case, i used `unxip`

```
brew install unxip
```

Then extract

```
unxip <Path-To-The-.xip-File>
```

Comment: Please do not post duplicate answers.

Answer (score -3):

You could just run:

```
open archive.xip
```