# How can I expand a .xip file on my USB into my internal hard drive?

Tags: xcode, macos, terminal, usb

I have saved the Xcode_12.2.xip file onto and external USB drive. How can I expand the file with the destination as my computer, say in downloads?

If this doesn't make sense I can provide more information.

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extract .xip files into a specific folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42197588/extract-xip-files-into-a-specific-folder)

Comment: @TamásSengel Worked for me in the same situation